# Cannot mount LVMm: resume ioctl on failed

Tags: partition, lvm, data-recovery, device-mapper

I wanted to resize my LVM, followed some tutorial on the net and the system totally crashed (I got some boot error with UUID not found). I ran a LiveCD and tried to at least recover some files but I can't mount the drive. I did pvcreate with the missing UUID on /dev/sda1. When in most tutorials I should do

```
vgchange -ay
```

and then mount I get:

```
device-mapper: resume ioctl on  failed: Invalid argument.
```

dmseg prints something like this:

```
device-mapper: table: 252:0: sda1 too small for target: start=2048, len=15499264, dev_size=497664
```

Mount obviously doesn't work. I'm totally stuck there and I damn need to recover these files. Any ideas?

Edit:
I need a single folder, any workaround way to get it out (might do on Windows Host, it's a VDI disk) would be okay.

Comment: What's the command you used to resize? If I had to guess it looks like one of the PV's was reduced at the block level without updating the PV metadata. You may try your luck with `pvresize`

Comment: Also, am I reading it properly that you've since ran a `pvcreate` on the physical volume?

Comment: it was some tool that run in the console and let me 'maximize' the partition. then it asked to reboot and then it didn't boot at all. Yep. One of them was something like 'unknown' and the system could not find its UUID.

Comment: Is that PV showing up as part of that volume group when you do a `pvs` ? I think re-writing the LVM header on that PV may have been a mistake as well. Did you [use the --restorefile option?](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html). Simply creating a PV with the same UUID might not be enough. It may get things to where it stops complaining about a missing PV but I think extent allocations are in the header as well.

Comment: I did --restore file, didn't work either. I posted the correct answer below. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying hundreds of different command line combinations I found a tutorial (originally targetting other problem) with gparted livecd. I booted it, then in terminal:

```
testdisk
```

Chose the first option, then chose:

```
write
```

It allowed me to mount the disk and recover the folder I needed.